# Facebook embedded autoplay

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need for an embedden video from facebook to autoplay, i read the documendation on their Graph API and i saw that i should put data-autoplay="true" in the iframe generated, but it still doesn't autoplay

here is the embedded html created by facebook that i'm trying to use with the previous cited variable:

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?height=476&href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FNASAHubble%2Fvideos%2F542706234014732%2F&show_text=true&width=427&t=0" width="427" height="591" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" data-autoplay="true" allow="autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
```

for the embedded video to autoplay as the page load

Comment: _"and i saw that i should put data-autoplay="true" in the iframe generated"_ - no, that's for when you use the other version, that gets loaded via the JS SDK. You can try and append `&autoplay=true` to the iframe src URL, but you'll have to see if that actually works.